# AbstractMethodError while using with SmileFactory?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have recently started using `Jackon` and `SmileFactory API's` to serialize the JSON document but somehow I am getting exception whenever I am trying to serialize it using `SmileFactory`

Below is my main class code which will use Value class to make a JSON document using Jackson and then serialize the JSON using ObjectMapper and also I am using SmileFactory here to serialize it into Binary Data format but whenever I try to use, it always gives me exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("id", 123);
        properties.put("test", 200);
        properties.put("marks", 100);

        Value val = new Value();
        val.setProperties(properties);

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(val);
        System.out.println(json);

        // this line is giving me an exception
        byte[] smileEncoded = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory()).writeValueAsBytes(val);
        System.out.println(smileEncoded);

}
```

Below is my Value class which is using Jackson to make a JSON document and will use ObjectMapper to serialize the document.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = { "v" })
public class Value {

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    @JsonCreator
    public Value() {
        properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }


    /**
     * Gets the properties of this attribute value.
     * @return the properties of this attribute value.
     */
    @JsonProperty("v")
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the properties of this attribute value.
     * @param v the properties of this attribute value to set
     */
    @JsonProperty("v")
    public void setProperties(Map<String, Object> v) {
        properties = v;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception
        }

        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }    
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(JsonGenerator.java:516)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:444)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
```

Maven Dependencies I have -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-smile</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: What versions of jackson are you using? List out all the jackson libs you have.

Comment: Updated the question with details..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing all sorts of library versions. `com.fasterxml.jackson` is the newest version of `jackson` while `org.codehaus.jackson` is the older version.

I don't know what other dependencies you might have in your project, but you should upgrade to the newest version of jackson

```
<!-- JSON serialization -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Where `jackson.version` can be `2.1.1`, like you have, or higher. [See here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core).

---

Alternatively, you can revert your `jackson-mapper-asl` version to `1.6.0`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The `1.6.0` version has a `JsonGeneratorBase` class which implements the `abstract` `JsonGenerator#writeFieldName(String)` method. Version `1.9.13` does not, that's why you get a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`. That javadoc for that error states

> this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class
>   has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last
>   compiled.

So you are simply using incompatible compiled versions of the classes.